# Blender order of execution

Tags: game-engine, visibility

I got a test project where I created 2 gauges composed of 20 planes for every 5% each. First one works great and update nicely, second don't even show any planes. I tracked the results with a isVisible boolean parameter where i assign them if the gauge is supposed to be visible or not.

[image]

No matter if the object visibility is setted on, nothing appears. I'm wondering if there is a limit of event triggers at the same time in the same scene or something like that

Can you guys help me with this issue?

Comment: Are both your visibility actuators supposed to be set to make the object visible?

Comment: No, one for being visible, other one off when float value is not in wanted interval. I noticed that even new mesh copied of old ones and all logic blocks removed is not appearing

Comment: I also tried via a python script and didn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the objects assigned meshes, like they were visible in designer but not in code behind. So I just erase all planes of my second gauge and copied the first one gauge's planes and assigned the proper value to be used. All work fine now.